# "ablation on" or "ablation of"

Tags: word-usage

Ablation studies are commonly used in academic publications to investigate the individual impact of a smaller subset of changes.
In this context, I would like to know when do we use "ablation on" or "ablation of"?

Comment: Could you provide the sentence you want to write? Prepositions are notoriously difficult to divine because they depend heavily on the desired meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Some context is needed to answer this question. What sort of ablation? Ablation of cardiac tissue? Ablation of mineral surfaces? Ablation of Ice? of paint? Marine ablation? By laser, by abrasion, by destructive heating,  by chipping? None of these usual uses of the word is appropriate to the terms of your question, which seem instead to refer to the logical processes of *analysis* or *reduction*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform an ablation (removal) **on** the whole of an object:

> [EP Lab digest](https://www.eplabdigest.com/article/3920) From 2004, Vol. 4, No. 7: *At Lenox Hill Hospital in New York, they recently performed an ablation on a young gentlemen with WPW syndrome.*

But if you want to specify what is being ablated, then it is an "ablation **of**" something:

> 1967   Brain 90 256   *It appeared that the cortex was involved in the myoclonus itself, as the jerks were abolished by ablation of the motor area.*

and this is the most frequent use.

However, please bear in mind that the most frequent use is not necessarily the appropriate use.